# cannot remove backslash or hyphen symbol from string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the current url and replace it with the h1 element text and add spaces between the words. The urls contain backslashes and hyphens so i need to remove them. I tried removing them, but my code didn't work. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //var newTitle = window.location.pathname; 
    var newTitle = '/fall-2012';
    newTitle.replace('-', ' ');
    newTitle.replace('/',' ');

   $('h1').hide();
   $('h1').text(newTitle);
   $('h1').show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Old Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript strings are immutable, so you need to assign the result of the replacement back to the original string:

```js
var newTitle = '/fall-2012';
newTitle = newTitle.replace(/[\/-]+/g, '');
console.log(newTitle);
```

Note that I chose to use a regex replacement here, targeting both forward slash and dash in a single go, which avoids making multiple calls to non regex `replace`.

Comment: @tsh You're right; I figured that out the hard way.

Comment: I think the key in this answer is calling out the immutability. OP's method would be usable if the assignment was present.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //var newTitle = window.location.pathname; 
    var newTitle = '/fall-2012';
    newTitle=newTitle.replace('-', ' ').replace('/',' ');
    
   $('h1').hide();
   $('h1').text(newTitle);
   $('h1').show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Old Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```js
var newTitle = '/fall-2012';
newTitle = newTitle.replace('-', ' ');
newTitle = newTitle.replace('/', ' ');
console.log(newTitle)
```

If you **don't want space** you can do this way

```js
var newTitle = '/fall-2012';
newTitle = newTitle.replace('-', '');
newTitle = newTitle.replace('/', '');
console.log(newTitle)
```

Answer (score 1):

***The reason is that strings are immutable – they cannot change, we can only ever make new strings.***

[String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

> The `replace()` method ***returns a new string*** with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match. If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced.
>
> ***The original string is left unchanged.***

You can do it with a single `replace()` using RegExp like the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //var newTitle = window.location.pathname; 
    var newTitle = '/fall-2012';
    newTitle = newTitle.replace(/[-/]/g, ' ');

   $('h1').hide();
   $('h1').text(newTitle);
   $('h1').show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Old Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In javascript, strings are immutable. No string methods change the string they operate on, they all return new strings.
```

If the requirement to replace the hyphen and backslash with space on their first occurrence in the URL then please add the below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //var newTitle = window.location.pathname; 
  var newTitle = '/fall-2012';
  newTitle = newTitle.replace('-', ' ').replace('/', ' ');
  $('h1').hide();
  $('h1').text(newTitle);
  $('h1').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Old Title</h1>
```

And if the requirement to replace every occurrence of hyphen and backslash with space in the URL then the below will help you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //var newTitle = window.location.pathname; 
  var newTitle = '/fall-2012';
  newTitle = newTitle.replace(/[-/]/g, ' ');
  $('h1').hide();
  $('h1').text(newTitle);
  $('h1').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Old Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use character class.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //var newTitle = window.location.pathname; 
    var newTitle = '/fall-2012';
    newTitle = newTitle.replace(/[/-]/g,'');

   $('h1').hide();
   $('h1').text(newTitle);
   $('h1').show();

});
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/b8jhg1vz/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do with `.replace(/[\/-]+/g, '')`